# How to verify account without transfer to another page, using jsf, ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets

I wan to login but don't transfer to another page. When click the Sign In button or link, it will pass value of username and password to server, then verify the account in database. If this account is not existed, I want show an alert or a message. How to achieve it? Some people told me that I should use ajax, but how? Thanks.

Here is jsf code sample:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="username" required="true"
                 value="#{loginManagedBean.username}" />
    <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true"
                   value="#{loginManagedBean.password}" />
    <h:commandLink type="submit"
                   id="login_button" value="Sign In" />
</h:form>
```

Sorry, I forget. I use the lasted version of jsf.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I use the the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your view code to add the ajax function :

```
<h:form id="loginform">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not loginManagedBean.isLogged}">
        <h:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{loginManagedBean.username}" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true" value="#{loginManagedBean.password}" />
        <h:commandLink id="login_button" value="Sign In">
            <f:ajax listener="#{loginManagedBean.onButtonLoginClick}" render="loginform" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{loginManagedBean.isLogged}">
        <h:commandLink id="logout_button" value="Sign Out">
            <f:ajax listener="#{loginManagedBean.onButtonLogoutClick}" render="loginform" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

And change your bean to something like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginManagedBean
{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    public boolean getIsLogged()
    {
        return false;// change to verify in session if logged
    }

    public void onButtonLoginClick(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        // Do the login stuff verification, put your user in session, etc
    }

    public void onButtonLogoutClick(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        // Do the logout stuff verification, remove your user in session, etc
    }
}
```

Note : You can also add login error messages and show them with `<h:message />`.

**More info :**

[using Ajax with Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkabr.html)